# How do I load files from a specific relative path in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I'm making a gem for internal use. In it, I load some YAML from another directory:

```
# in <project_root>/bin/magicwand
MagicWand::Configuration::Initializer.new(...)

# in <project_root>/lib/magicwand/configuration/initializer.rb
root_yaml = YAML.load_file(
  File.expand_path("../../../../data/#{RootFileName}", __FILE__))

# in <project_root>/data/root.yaml
---
apple:   100
banana:  200
coconut: 300
```

I'd rather not depend on the location of `data/root.yaml` relative to `initializer.rb`. Instead, I'd rather get a reference to `<project_root>` and depend on the relative path from there, which seems like a smarter move.

First, is that the best way to go about this? Second, if so, how do I do that? I checked out the various `File` methods, but I don't think there's anything like that. I'm using Ruby 1.9.

Right now, I create a special constant and depend on that instead:

```
# in lib/magicwand/magicwand.rb
module MagicWand
  # Project root directory.
  ROOT = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
end
```

but I'm not sure I like that approach either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's a main file you always run you can use that file as a reference point. The relative path (between the current directory and) of that file will be in `$0`, so to get the relative path to `data/root.yaml` (assuming that is the relative path between the main file and `root.yaml`) you do

```
path_to_root_yaml = File.dirname($0) + '/data/root.yaml'
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but it would break during tests, when I often unit-test the classes directly rather than firing up the full application stack. My `$0` would be different in such cases (the path to the test runner, not my application).

Comment: Wrap the lookup in a simple object that you can stub out during testing.