# Rspec - Working directory

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a class that laod config file from `config/config.yml`.

```
class Example
  def initialize
    config = YAML.load_file('config/config.yml')
  end
end
```

I have created `proyect/spec/config/config.yml` example file but when I run the test it try load file `proyect/config/config.yml`.

How I change rspec working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Why not point the config to the right path?

```
class Example
  def initialize
    config = YAML.load_file('spec/config/config.yml')
  end
end
```

According to [this](http://ruby.11.x6.nabble.com/How-to-specify-current-directory-for-specs-td3484761.html), you can set the load_path like so

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift 'spec'
     or
$:.unshift 'spec'
```

Also according to that,

> As much as I like removing unnecessary requires in specs I prefer verbosity over magic -- anything that gives the code reader more clarity as to what's necessary for a particular example group.

Comment: Proyect is a gem that need load config from `config/config.yml' like [mongoid](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid). I want to test that it is done correctly.

Comment: or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592554/best-way-to-create-custom-config-options-for-my-rails-app) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075855/how-do-i-load-files-from-a-specific-relative-path-in-ruby)